# Apple bug? UICollectionView targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

I see others questions on StackOverflow saying that i need to make sure that the paging is set to off. But I have done this and still it is not called.

Is there any thing i am missing?

Here is the sample project on [Github](https://github.com/patchthecode/testCollectionView). There is no code in it at all except the code to setup a collection view.

here is the code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return proposedContentOffset
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618007-collectionview),

> The proposed point (in the coordinate space of the collection view’s content view) for the upper-left corner of the visible content. This represents the point that the collection view has calculated as the most likely value **to use for the animations or layout update**.

In other words, it's called when you delete or insert cells to collection view.

Answer (score 5):

You might be thinking of `targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:)`

```
override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    var contentOffset = proposedContentOffset

    // do something with contentOffset

    return contentOffset
}
```

with `isPagingEnabled` set to false on the collection view.